# Cordova WebSocket with client side certificates (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, cordova, ssl, websocket, wss

I'd like to create a secure Connection (SSL/TLS) between my client and my server.
Only a specific client is authorised to connect to the server.
Therefore, I created on the server a client certificate (openssl) to provided mutual authorization. On the serverside I already set up my WebSocketServer using require(ws)(Node.js) using the created server certs.
On the clientside I don't how the standard WebSocket API is providing me a way to attach my client certs.
Can anyone tell me how to create a client WebSocket passing certs to the server ?

I am developing in Cordova using Javascript.

The basic clientside API seems to be limited to this:
https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/

Interface:

```
interface WebSocket extends EventTarget {
binaryType: string;
readonly bufferedAmount: number;
readonly extensions: string;
onclose: (this: WebSocket, ev: CloseEvent) => any;
onerror: (this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any;
onmessage: (this: WebSocket, ev: MessageEvent) => any;
onopen: (this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any;
readonly protocol: string;
readonly readyState: number;
readonly url: string;
close(code?: number, reason?: string): void;
send(data: any): void;
readonly CLOSED: number;
readonly CLOSING: number;
readonly CONNECTING: number;
readonly OPEN: number;
addEventListener<K extends keyof WebSocketEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: WebSocket, ev: WebSocketEventMap[K]) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;}
```

Class:

```
declare var WebSocket: {
prototype: WebSocket;
new(url: string, protocols?: string | string[]): WebSocket;
readonly CLOSED: number;
readonly CLOSING: number;
readonly CONNECTING: number;
readonly OPEN: number;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this issue now.

Possible solution to my question I found finally was this plugin:
https://github.com/flynetworks/cordova-websocket-clientcert
Using the pkcs12 archive.

I am not happy with this solution and will change the client authentication from TLS client certificates to simple HTTP authentication.

See possibilites for authentication with WebSockets here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-10.5